# Tracking AdWords traffic from an unrelated account in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads

I have an Analytics account linked to my AdWords account, and have been using it to track progress of my campaigns.

Now I've started an AdWords campaign with a third party, and would like to see their results in Analytics as well. My own campaign is stopped, but unfortunately the `google (cpc)` traffic source has zero hits.

Nonetheless, the `google (organic)` results have increased significantly, which seems to indicate that those visitors are counted there. This is unfortunate in may ways, since I can't distinguish between real organic visitors and paid-for visitors.

What can I do to differentiate between organic and paid-for visitors in case of an unlinked AdWords account?

Answer (score 1):

Create a parameter for your CPC links. In your AdWords ads, set your page URL to `something.php?source=cpc`.

You can also use bit.ly links.