# Display only visits referred from a Google Adwords campain

Tags: google-analytics, traffic, google-ads

I want to only display visits to my site which were sent by my Google Adwords campain preferably in the Visitors overview page.

I've tried filtering with 'Advanced Segments' but when I select "Paid Search Traffic" visits goes down to zero. But I do know that most of my visitors at the moment are being sent from Google Adwords.

In [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6170/tracking-adwords-traffic-from-an-unrelated-account-in-google-analytics) the answer (which was not chosen) suggested adding a HTTP GET request or an URL shortener, but surly there is a way to do it in Analytics?

Comment: For some reason all the visits are being shown as 'direct traffic', but it's actually traffic from adwords

Comment: Is your AdWords account linked to your Analytics account?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is likely relating to you not having either:

1. auto tagging enabled within adwords
2. customised url tagging added to the landing pages for your ads.

You should have only one of the above, however, to accurately track your sources you will need to ensure one of the above enabled (google adwords autotagging is by far the easiest).

If you do have tracking enabled you should firstly check where your traffic is coming from
(left side menu) Traffic Sources > Sources > All Traffic

If your traffic medium is being recorded from the CPC source apply a custom segment selecting 'medium' and 'cpc' [or whatever the paid advertising medium is being recorded as - from adwords it should be cpc]

I hope this helps :)